# 33% + 33% + 34% is not the same width as 100% on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive-design

I'm running into a situation where 3 divs with widths of 33%, 34%, and 33% do not add up to the same number of pixels as one div with 100% width.  Consider the following complete html snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ios math test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:3em; background-color: green;"></div>
    <div style="width:33%; height:3em; float:left; background-color: red;"></div>
    <div style="width:34%; height:3em; float:left; background-color: red;"></div>
    <div style="width:33%; height:3em; float:left; background-color: red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll notice that safari on iphones, ipads, and even some desktop instances of IOS will show the div that has 100% as being longer than the sum of the widths of the divs below it.   This seems strange, and either suggests that my understanding of how widths work is flawed, or IOS is messing with our heads.

All apple devices that I've tested exhibit this behavior(safari on a macbook, safari on an ipad, safari on an iphone, chrome on an ipad, chrome on an iphone, etc...).   It does not exhibit this behavior when using chrome on a windows box, or safari on a windows box, or android.

Here's a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/zd6wx/

What's the correct way to represent this on an IOS device (safari, chrome, etc...) that also renders correctly on other devices (eg... android)?   I don't want to use tables, and I only want to use javascript as an option of last resort.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the box-sizing attribute. To cover all broswers use:

```
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
  box-sizing: border-box;
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/5gfdZ/1/

Comment: If I look at that jsfiddle example using an ipad, it still shows up with inconsistent widths.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I also confirmed that your suggested solution does not work on an iphone running ios 7.1.1 using either safari or chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... maybe is caused by computed style of Safari Mobile.

Can you try to put a reset rule like this?

```
<style>
    div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, span, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-family: arial, sans serif;
        color: black;
        line-height: normal;
    }
</style>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference either.   The edges of the two rows of divs are still inconsistent.